# Need to selectively remove newline characters from a file using unix (solaris)

Tags: parsing, unix

I am trying to find a way to selectively remove newline characters from a file.  I have no issues removing all of them..but I need some to remain.

Here is the example of the bad input file.  Note that rows with Permit ID COO789 & COO012 have newlines embedded in the description field that I need to remove.

```
"Permit Id","Permit Name","Description","Start Date","End Date"
"COO123","Music Festival",,"02/12/2013","02/12/2013"
"COO456","Race Weekend",,"02/23/2013","02/23/2013"
"COO789","Basketball Final 8 Championships - Media vs. Politicians
Skills Competition",,"02/22/2013","02/22/2013"
"COO012","Dragonboat race 
weekend",,"05/11/2013","05/11/2013"
```

Here is an example of how I need the file to look like:

```
"Permit Number/Id","Permit Name","Description","Start Date","End Date"
"COO123","Music Festival",,"02/12/2013","02/12/2013"
"COO456","Race Weekend",,"02/23/2013","02/23/2013"
"COO789","Basketball Final 8 Championships - Media vs. Politicians Skills Competition",,"02/22/2013","02/22/2013"
"COO012","Dragonboat race weekend",,"05/11/2013","05/11/2013"
```

NOTE:  I did simplify the file by removing a few extra columns.  The logic should be able to accommodation any number of columns though.  The actual full header line is with all columns is.  Technically, I expect the "extra" newlines to be found in Description and Location columns.

```
"Permit Number/Id","Permit Name","Description","Start Date","End Date","Custom Status","Owner Name","Total Expected Attendance","Location"
```

I have tried sed, cut, tr, nawk, etc.  Open to any solution that can do this..that can be called from within a unix script.

Thanks!!!

Comment: so it's basically a CSV file?

Comment: So what's the algorithm? Substitute newline character while line finishes with...?

Comment: If you're loading this data into Oracle, there are options you can use to leave embedded CR in place. Good luck.

Comment: Yes, it is a CSV file.  I tried to get the source to define the end of a line, but their system cannot do that.  I am loading it into Oracle via SQL*Loader which is where it fails as the rows don't follow the expected layout.  Was attempting to fix the source of the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must remove newline characters from only within the 'Description' and 'Location' fields, you will need a proper csv parser (think Text::CSV). You could also do this fairly easily using `GNU awk`, but you won't have access to `gawk` on Solaris unfortunately. Therefore, the next best solution would be to join lines that don't start with a double-quote to the previous line. You can do this using `sed`. I've written this with compatibility in mind:

```
sed -e :a -e '$!N; s/ *\n\([^"]\)/ \1/; ta' -e 'P;D' file
```

Results:

```
"Permit Id","Permit Name","Description","Start Date","End Date"
"COO123","Music Festival",,"02/12/2013","02/12/2013"
"COO456","Race Weekend",,"02/23/2013","02/23/2013"
"COO789","Basketball Final 8 Championships - Media vs. Politicians Skills Competition",,"02/22/2013","02/22/2013"
"COO012","Dragonboat race weekend",,"05/11/2013","05/11/2013"
```

Comment: Awesome!  That appears to work perfectly.   Really appreciate you help everyone!  Thanks Steve for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/ \n/ /g'
```

Reads the whole file into the pattern space, then removes all newlines which occur directly after a space - assuming that all the errant newlines fit this pattern. If not, when else should newlines be removed?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  However it does not seem to work in Solaris. I have tried different shells with no luck as well.    cat test_data.dat  | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/ \n/ /g' produces "ba;s/: Event not found" under csh and "Label too long: :a;N;$!ba;s/ \n/ /g" under other shells.