# Need help in understanding "sed -e :a -e '$!N; s/ *\n\([^"]\)/ \1/; ta' -e 'P;D' file"

Tags: sed, command

I have a source file containing 15 columns and some columns have a new line character within the data and I need to delete them preserving the record delimiter which also happens to be the new line character.

Have seen a solution

```
sed -e :a -e '$!N; s/ *\n\([^"]\)/ \1/; ta' -e 'P;D' file
```

in the post below

[Need to selectively remove newline characters from a file using unix (solaris)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834801/need-to-selectively-remove-newline-characters-from-a-file-using-unix-solaris)

but cant comment there as I don't have enough reputation.

Could some one help me understand the sed command ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
-e
```

action list in string after this

```
:a
```

define a label (for a goto jump)

```
$!N
```

if not last line, load a new line to the working buffer (add a line to treat for next action) (if on last line, skip and go to next action)

```
s/ *\n\([^"]\)/ \1/
```

replace  space (any number of) + newline followed by anything but `"` (any number of) [keep this in memory n°1] by  space + content of memory

```
ta
```

if there is a replacment, go to label `a` (restart the cycle until now)

```
P
```

Print first line of current working buffer

```
D
```

Delete first line and go to end of action list (so load a new line into buffer and restart if not at last line)

so this sed will remove any New Line that are under certain sequence (in fact dur to use of * in the sequence, it will remove any New Line of the file followed by something that is not `"` that is certainly your field content end delimiter

Comment: Many Thanks for the elaborate explanation, Based on the above I presume it wont work if the new line occurs in the end of a field which is not the last in the record and is double quoted.
In my case the fields are not quoted but I know for sure that there would be 15 fields on every record. Is there a viable solution in my case ?

Comment: problem is mainly to define the field content. Something has to be assumed like the separator( ex `,`) so we can take each 15 field and replace `\n` inside in this case. (awk should maybe be better using the FS value for this)

Comment: yes, the fields are seperated by comma but are not quoted. Currently looking at the usage of getline but its complicated :( . I can write a C code to fix this but need a unix approach.

Answer (score 0):

another post (for clarity, the other is explanation of your sed)

```
sed -e ':a
   s/\([^,]*,\)\{14\}\(.*\)/&/
   t rmNL
   N
   b a
: rmNL
   s/\n//g' YourFile
```

Try this BUT, there could be no new line in 15th field (because there is no way to know if it is part of filed or real new record or content of this new record first line)

load new line until there are 15 separated content by a `,`, then remove any NewLine inside